# Unit testing a Vuetify Data Table with Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, axios, vuetify.js

I have created a Vue.js application with Vuetify and am now trying to unit test a component containing a Vuetify Data Table. The Data Table is populated from a backend REST API using Axios which works fine when I run the application, however in my unit test (where I mock out Axios with Jest) the Data Table is never populated

Here is the source for my Component

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Results
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          append-icon="mdi-magnify"
          label="Search"
          single-line
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="results"
        :search="search"
        :loading="loading"
        loading-text="Loading results..."
        :custom-sort="customSort"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.startTime="{item}">{{formatDate(item.startTime)}}</template>
        <template v-slot:item.endTime="{item}">{{formatDate(item.endTime)}}</template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';

function dateArrayToMoment(date) {
  return moment()
    .year(date[0])
    .month(date[1])
    .date(date[2])
    .hour(date[3])
    .minute(date[4]);
}

export default {
  name: 'ResultsList',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      search: '',
      headers: [
        { text: 'Task', align: 'start', sortable: false, value: 'title' },
        { text: 'State', value: 'state' },
        { text: 'Start Time', value: 'startTime' },
        { text: 'End Time', value: 'endTime' },
        { text: 'Result', value: 'resultMessage' }
      ],
      results: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadResults();
  },
  methods: {
    async loadResults() {
      try {
        let response = await axios.get('BACKEND_SERVER/results', {});
        this.results = response.data;
        this.loading = false;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
      } catch (error) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(error);
        // you can handle different errors differently
        // or just display an error message instead of your table using a <v-if> tag
        // or navigate to an error page
      }
    },
    formatDate(date) {
      return dateArrayToMoment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
    },
    customSort(items, index, isDesc) {
      items.sort((a, b) => {
        if (index[0] == 'startTime' || index[0] == 'endTime') {
          if (!isDesc[0]) {
            return (
              dateArrayToMoment(b[index]).toDate() -
              dateArrayToMoment(a[index]).toDate()
            );
          } else {
            return (
              dateArrayToMoment(a[index]).toDate() -
              dateArrayToMoment(b[index]).toDate()
            );
          }
        }
      });
      return items;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is the test spec that tests the component

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import ResultsList from '@/components/ResultsList'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import axios from 'axios'
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const localVue = createLocalVue()

var results = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'state': 'COMPLETED',
    'startTime': [2020, 4, 21, 19, 42],
    'endTime': [2020, 4, 21, 19, 42],
    'type': 'Example Scheduled Task',
    'title': 'Example Scheduled Task at 2020-04-21 19:42:00',
    'resultMessage': 'Task finished successfully'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'state': 'COMPLETED',
    'startTime': [2020, 4, 22, 13, 36],
    'endTime': [2020, 4, 22, 13, 36],
    'type': 'Example Scheduled Task',
    'title': 'Example Scheduled Task at 2020-04-22 13:36:00',
    'resultMessage': 'Task finished successfully'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'state': 'COMPLETED',
    'startTime': [2020, 4, 22, 13, 37],
    'endTime': [2020, 4, 22, 13, 37],
    'type': 'Example Scheduled Task',
    'title': 'Example Scheduled Task at 2020-04-22 13:37:00',
    'resultMessage': 'Task finished successfully'
  }
];

// Use Jest to mock the Axios
jest.mock('axios');

describe('ResultsList.vue', () => {
  let vuetify

  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify()

    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(results);
  })

  it('should have a custom title and match snapshot', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(ResultsList, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      propsData: {
        title: 'Foobar',
      },
    })

    await flushPromises()

    // With jest we can create snapshot files of the HTML output
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot()

  })
})
```

As you can see I use Jest to mock out Axios so it returns some test data and use Jest to verify a snapshot.

The problem is the snapshot doesn't contain any data (test or otherwise) despite calling flushPromises to ensure all promises are resolved before taking the snapshot.

Here is the snapshot. As you can see no data is displayed in the Data Table, test or otherwise.

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`ResultsList.vue should match snapshot 1`] = `
<div class="container container--fluid" title="Foobar">
  <div class="v-card v-sheet theme--light">
    <div class="v-card__title">
      Results
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="v-input v-input--hide-details theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--single-line">
        <div class="v-input__control">
          <div class="v-input__slot">
            <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label for="input-4" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; position: absolute;">Search</label><input id="input-4" type="text"></div>
            <div class="v-input__append-inner">
              <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--append"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-magnify theme--light"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-data-table theme--light">
      <div class="v-data-table__wrapper">
        <table>
          <colgroup>
            <col class="">
            <col class="">
            <col class="">
            <col class="">
            <col class="">
          </colgroup>
          <thead class="v-data-table-header">
            <tr>
              <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Task" class="text-start"><span>Task</span></th>
              <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="State: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending." aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable"><span>State</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon mdi mdi-arrow-up theme--light" style="font-size: 18px;"></i></th>
              <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Start Time: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending." aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable"><span>Start Time</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon mdi mdi-arrow-up theme--light" style="font-size: 18px;"></i></th>
              <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="End Time: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending." aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable"><span>End Time</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon mdi mdi-arrow-up theme--light" style="font-size: 18px;"></i></th>
              <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Result: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending." aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable"><span>Result</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon mdi mdi-arrow-up theme--light" style="font-size: 18px;"></i></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="v-data-table__empty-wrapper">
              <td colspan="5">No data available</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="v-data-footer">
        <div class="v-data-footer__select">Rows per page:<div class="v-input v-input--hide-details v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-text-field v-select">
            <div class="v-input__control">
              <div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="list-17" class="v-input__slot">
                <div class="v-select__slot">
                  <div class="v-select__selections">
                    <div class="v-select__selection v-select__selection--comma">10</div><input aria-label="$vuetify.dataTable.itemsPerPageText" id="input-17" readonly="readonly" type="text" aria-readonly="false" autocomplete="off">
                  </div>
                  <div class="v-input__append-inner">
                    <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--append"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-menu-down theme--light"></i></div>
                  </div><input type="hidden" value="10">
                </div>
                <div class="v-menu">
                  <!---->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="v-data-footer__pagination">–</div>
        <div class="v-data-footer__icons-before"><button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="v-btn v-btn--disabled v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default" aria-label="Previous page"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-left theme--light"></i></span></button></div>
        <div class="v-data-footer__icons-after"><button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="v-btn v-btn--disabled v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round v-btn--text theme--light v-size--default" aria-label="Next page"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-right theme--light"></i></span></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Comment: I am curious what you came up with here.  My knee jerk answer is I wonder if when you're mocking out Axios that it's only returning the mock and ignoring your data here.

Comment: Another suggestion to, I would separate your code into more useful modules.  Take your axios HTTP call out and put it in it's own service for that particular API and the use this component to control only the data table.
This way when testing you can use embedded data and not have to rely on Axios.  Axios is an external reference, yes it blocks your data table from being populated if it fails, but that's an issue with Axios, not your data table.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:
Call `wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` before you take the snapshot.

Instead of using `Vue.use()`, try `localVue.use(Vuetify)`

Comment: Have tried that but doesn't make a difference I'm afraid